# Does doublewrite buffering guaranteed to prevent page tear on NVMe SSD drives?

Tags: database, storage

In the context of database systems, doublewrite buffering is a well-known technique used by databases (MySQL/InnoDB [in particular](https://www.percona.com/blog/innodb-double-write/)) to make sure the written page is not torn if the system experience power loss during page write. It is based on the fact that classical HDDs can write only one place on the disk at a time. If the page is written twice at different locations at least one copy of the page will be correctly written. There are some optimizations to this process, but basically it means *if you cannot write several places on the disk simultaneously, you can screw only single place at a time* .

Now NVMe SSDs can write multiple streams of the data in parallel. Does that mean that double-write buffering in theory can not prevent page tear? If not what system components provides safety guarantees?